# Building A React-native app for ios in a mac ventura virtual machine fails with createItemModels already exists error

Tags: ios, react-native, macos, ventura

I have been trying to build a react native app for ios in a macos ventura virtual machine . I'm new to mac so it took me plenty of time to reach this point .
it gives me this error message `createItemModels creation requirements should not create capability item model for a capability item model that already exists.`
I have followed the documentation , created the project and ran `npx pod install`
I also went through many hoops to install cocoapods with the ruby version being not compatible and ran `pod install` in a previous attempt but it gave the same error and fails to build

the commands I ran from the start was as follows

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

brew install node
brew install watchman

brew install ruby@3.1

export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
export GEM_HOME=/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
export GEM_PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0

brew install cocoapods
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject/ios
npx pod install
```

the full log of the build process is in this text file

[building process log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OYa98HDVuzK03cEJbGUEmJstRUY_HLbd/view?usp=sharing)